# Auto Logout user when a tab is closed or browser closed from task manager in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, codeigniter-3

Following is my code that I'm using to logout user after 10 mins of inactivity.

```
var timer = 0;
    function set_interval() {
        timer = setInterval("auto_logout()", 300000);
    }

    function reset_interval() {

        if (timer != 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = 0;
            timer = setInterval("auto_logout()", 300000);
        }
    }

    function auto_logout() {
        window.location = "<?php echo base_url('staff/staff_logout'); ?>";
    }
```

As for the logging out when browser closes that also has been taken care in the **config.php** file by doing `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;`

But now I want to do it when a tab is closed so I tried the following code:-

```
var unloadEvent = function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = "Warning: Leaving this page will result in any unsaved data being lost. Are you sure you wish to continue?";

        return confirmationMessage;
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadEvent);
```

But it's not working. I'm using Chrome 71.0.3578.98. Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't show the confirmation message with `window.confirm`

Comment: @HerrSerker I actually want the user to be logged out if he/she closes the tab so for that I have used beforeunload but it's not happening in chrome. can give me an example??

Comment: [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event should show a confirmation message when page is unloaded. Alas this fires when you click on a link and not only, when you close the tab

Comment: You cannot destinguish between a tab close and a follow link event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3888938/476951

Comment: You may want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload though

Comment: This may be a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057659/476951